# Using Mobilefirst database for jsonstore sync

Tags: database, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing an Hybrid application using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3.

We don't know if we can use the database that we installed during the MobileFirst installation.

It's a bad practice to use this database as a backend for our apps?
Will this generate a overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileFirst Server that is installed in the Development environment (the Eclipse plug-in) uses a filesystem-based database (HSQL) by default.

The MobileFirst Server that is installed in a QA/Production environment supports a database from these vendors: MySQL, Oracle, DB2.

In both cases the the database that is created for the use of the MobileFirst Server should be used solely by MobileFirst Server. *It should not function as a backend to store other information in it for use by the applications*, that are served by the MobileFirst Server.

It should be separately hosted databases - it can be on the same machine if it is able and has enough resources, but it should be different databases.

Comment: A single database process might manage a number of logical databases. I had not thought there was an issue in having application data in its own logical database, in its own schema. Is this approach consistent with your advice here "different database"?

Comment: Yes. I mean that of course you can have a database with multiple schemes within. Just don't use the WRKLGHT database for example for other purposes.